# Error while concatenating audio files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

While concatenating audio files with

```
ffmpeg -safe 0  -f concat 
-segment_time_metadata 1 
-i {m3u_file_name} 
-vf select=concatdec_select 
-af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 {ogg_file_name}
```

I get the following output

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, concat, from 'fm3u.m3u':
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.006500, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ogg, to 'fout.ogg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libvorbis
[opus @ 0x558b2c245400] Error parsing the packet header.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[opus @ 0x558b2c245400] Error parsing the packet header.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[opus @ 0x558b2c245400] Error parsing the packet header.
...
...
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[opus @ 0x558b2c245400] Error parsing the packet header.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
size=      47kB time=00:00:10.84 bitrate=  35.2kbits/s speed=4.38x    
video:0kB audio:42kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:3kB muxing overhead: 10.251080%
/fout.ogg
```

The final audio sounds good.

ffprobe on the 2 participating files looks like

```
# ffprobe <FILE>

ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'f1.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:01.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 34 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp

# ffprobe <FILE>
ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'f2.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 80 kb/s
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.107.100 libvorbis
```

What is the reason of the error?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362868/4752223)

"file-level concatenation (-f concat) requires all files in the listing to have the exact same codec parameters. "

In this case, the input files have codecs `opus` and `vorbis`.

---

To resolve the issue, I recreated some files (silence files) so they all have the same CODEC as the files I am mixing them with.

In particular, instead of creating them using:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono -t 5.8 -c:a libvorbis silence-5.8.ogg
```

I use now (note libopus)

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono -t 5.8 -c:a libopus silence-5.8.ogg
```

And the "concat with ffmpeg" works without any problem.

I also tried

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono -t 5.8 -c:a opus silence-5.8.ogg
```

But that returns with

```
[opus @ 0x5607f1765900] The encoder 'opus' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
[opus @ 0x5607f1765900] Alternatively use the non experimental encoder 'libopus'.
```

So, `libopus` works just fine (no need for opus)